# how to copy files matching a regex using ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a bunch of files on a specific `files/` folder. Some files have different extensions. I want to copy to a target directory only files ending in a specific extension.
I tried this but it does not work.

```
  - name: Copy only .txt files
    copy:
      src: files/*.txt
      dest: /var/files/
```

In this case I only need need to copy 3 files, so I can create a new task per file, but I was wondering how to do this if I want to match a regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have these **files stored at the controller**

```sh
shell> tree files
files
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.sh
```

It's possible to use [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria). Delegate the task to the localhost. Otherwise, the task would look for the files at the remote host. For example

```yaml
    - find:
        path: files
        file_type: file
        use_regex: false
        patterns:
          - '*.txt'
      register: result
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

give the list of the files

```yaml
  msg:
  - files/file2.txt
  - files/file1.txt
```

Then, use the list and copy the files

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: var/files
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

---

When the **files are stored at the remote host**

- remove `delegate_to: localhost` from the *find* task and
- set `remote_src: true` (default: false) in the *copy* task.